# Problems when print the server data received

Tags: python, sockets, printing

I have the next problem: When i use this code for a EchoServer with the python asyncio library

```
import asyncio


class EchoServer(asyncio.Protocol):

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        print('Message received: {}'.format(data.decode()), end='')
        self.transport.write(data + b'\n')

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('Client disconnected...')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = loop.create_server(EchoServer, '127.0.0.1', 12345)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
print('Listening on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    server.close()
    loop.close()
```

in this line

```
print('Message received: {}'.format(data.decode()), end='')
```

when i use: `end=''`, the messages from the client without `'\n'` don't log on the console and only show the messages received when client disconnected.
Like this:

```
Message received: testMessage received: testMessage received: testClient disconnected...
```

this message is show only when the client disconnect.

but when i use `'\n'` on the end of messages from the client the messages show on the console when the client send the messages. Like this:

```
Message received: test
Message received: test
Message received: test
client disconnected...
```

in this case in 3 diferents time and finally the client disconnect.
And when i use this line:

```
 print('Message received: {}'.format(data.decode()))
```

without `end=''`,works fine with the client messages without `'\n'` in the end of messages.

I want to know why.

The problem isnt with the console messages format, the problem is the time when the data received are show in the console.

PS: sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Do you know what `end=''` does? It is working exactly as it should.

Comment: Yes i know. The problem is when the messages are show in the console. When i use end=' ' i send a message from the client but it isnt show on the console in the same moment when i send. Only when the client disconnect all the messages are show together.

Comment: It does this way because it is waiting for the end of line to flush the buffer.

Comment: And then the data_received function is blocking while wait the end of line in the print line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manually flush stdout.

```
print('Message received: {}'.format(data.decode()), end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
```